# Is there any other method to call here map api?

Tags: heremaps

I am working on here map and getting this error
**"Uncaught ReferenceError: H is not defined"**
but I have passed all the required script.
Is there any other solution for this?

```
var platform = new H.service.Platform({
            'apikey':'key'
          });
```